# Do WSGI servers connect to devices outside of the network?

Tags: web-application, webserver, python

I want to set up a plotly dashboard and view it from my browser.

Plotly gets set up as a flask application. I'm of the understanding that I should use a WSGI server to host it. I'm looking at [waitress](https://pypi.org/project/waitress/) in particular.

Does waitress, or WSGI servers in general, connect to devices outside of the network? In other words, if I have a dashboard, will all the data and charts and other details about the dashboard stay local to my machine?

Comment: I am not sure if you have understood what a WSGI server does, it usually just forwards requests to the local Python application. TheWSGI does not provide that data it just passes them through. The Python server is the one that provides the content. In your case this is the dashboard server and where it stores it's data depends on it's implementation.

Comment: I guess I want to make sure that the server is running on my computer and not on waitress's computers. for example, would a wsgi server work even if my wifi was off and I had no connection to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

A WSGI application is just a server. It's fundamentally not different from IIS, Apache or Nginx. If your WSGI listens to `0.0.0.0`, anyone that have a direct route to your computer can access it.

> if I have a dashboard, will all the data and charts and other details about the dashboard stay local to my machine?

It depends on the configuration, not on WSGI. If you configure waitress `listen` directive as `listen="127.0.0.1:8080 [::1]:8080"`, only the local machine can access your data. If you configure as `listen="*:8080 *:6543"`, your data is accessible from anyone with direct routing to your computer (everyone in your LAN or Wifi, for example).

If you have a public IPv4 or IPv6, that means anyone knowing your IP can connect to it.

Again, this does not depend on Flask, WSGI, waitress, Apache or IIS. It depends on the configuration of the server.

Comment: To be clear, you're saying that a WSGI application never accessses computers owned by waitress, for example. It might be accessible on the local network but the data is never leaving that network (unless I explicity tell it to do so). Is that right?

Comment: No, I am saying that your data is accessible to any computer that can access yours.